# Unable to create table in MySQL using Doctrine and Symfony2

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am working with Symfony2 and Doctrine ORM using MySql .

After creating an Entity, I am not able to create the table. It throws an exception.

```
anu@anu-bridge:/var/www/Symfony$ php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force --dump-sql

[Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException]
The table with name 'product' already exists.  

doctrine:schema:update [--complete] [--dump-sql] [--force] [--em[="..."]]
```

I tried to drop it , but still it throws the error.

```
anu@anu-bridge:/var/www/Symfony$ php app/console doctrine:schema:drop --force
Dropping database schema...

[Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException]         
The table with name 'product' already exists.  

doctrine:schema:drop [--dump-sql] [--force] [--full-database] [--em[="..."]]

[Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException]         
The table with name 'product' already exists.
```

There is no tables in the database. Cleared all the cache for symfony and doctrine, but still the error is throwing.

Symfony2 version is 2.0.1 .

Comment: You might have more than one entity using the same table name.

Comment: No she doesn't have any other Entity. There is only one Product entity.

Answer (score 47):

I've had a similar problem. Most likely you have two entities named Category inside different Bundles. For instance:

```
src/Acme/SomeBundle/Entity/Product.php
src/Acme/OtherBundle/Entity/Product.php
```

Comment one of these files and retry the console command.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me out. Alternatively instead of commenting out the file, you can also set a custom table name, for example by using `@ORM\Table(name="something-else")`. That will also avoid any collision.

Comment: All the relations were okay in my project, the only issue was that indeed i had 2 entities in 2 different bundles. I decided 2 rebuild everything in one single Bundle (Symfony 3 AppBundle) to have only one entity of the same table and everything worked as expected without this error.

Answer (score 10):

I was getting this problem from a conflict with join table defined in an association class annotation and a join table defined in a ManyToMany annotation.

The mapping definitions in two entities with a direct ManytoMany relationship appeared to result in the automatic creation of the join table using the 'joinTable' annotation. However the join table was already defined by an annotation in its underlying entity class and I wanted it to use this association entity class's own field definitions so as to extend the join table with additional custom fields.

The explanation and solution was thanks to this post in the forum '[Doctrine Annotation Question](http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=36745&p=122235)'. This post draws attention to the Doctrine documentation regarding [ManyToMany Uni-directional relationships](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional). Look at the note regarding the approach of using an 'association entity class' thus replacing the many-to-many annotation mapping directly between two main entity classes with a one-to-many annotation in the main entity classes and two 'many-to-one' annotations in the Associative Entity class. There is an example provided in this forum post [Association models with extra fields](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/doctrine-user/cw8fyH9_ebY):

```
public class Person
{
    /** 
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="AssignedItems", mappedBy="person")
     */
    private $assignedItems;
}

public class Items
{
    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="AssignedItems", mappedBy="item")
     */
    private $assignedPeople;
}

public class AssignedItems
{
    /** 
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Person")
     * @JoinColumn(name="person_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $person;

    /** 
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Item")
     * @JoinColumn(name="item_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $item;
}
```

Comment: I ran into an issue when I executed the schema update command, doctrine told me the join table (AssignedItems in this example) already existed. I used the ManyToMany annotations in the Doctrine examples on just one table. I broke apart Doctrine code to ManyToOne like this example shows and Doctrine no longer complained. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I got this error when editing my Product.orm.yml file.

I added a new manyToMany relation with a Category entity, and made a mistake on the joinTable line :

```
manyToMany:
  categories:
    targetEntity: Acme\ProductBundle\Entity\Category
    inversedBy: products
    joinTable:
      name: Product  # My mistake: joinTable should be something like ProductCategory

    [...]
```

Indeed it's a silly error, I share anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you can, you can do this as this worked for me:

Drop the entire database:

`app/console doctrine:schema:drop --force --full-database`

Run all DB migrations:

`app/console doctrine:migrations:migrate`

Answer (score 1):

I imagine It can happen quite often when copying entities. In my case it was a ORM table name annotation that was misfortunately duplicated.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="category")
 * */
class Category {
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with an **One-To-Many, Unidirectional with Join Table** relation like ([see doctrine doc](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table)). I did not find this error case with this relation type through the internet or stackoverflow, so i post here my solution for let help others with the same problem.

What caused this problem:

1. After reverse engineering the legacy db tables with ORM ([see doc "How to Generate Entities from an Existing Database"](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html)), all tables **also only join tables** recieved an entity PHP class.
2. With annotations on a category entity i described the joining. Results this code:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="category_child",
 *     joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *     inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="category_child_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
public $children;
```

3. The `@ORM\JoinTable(name="category_child"` caused that doctrine wants to create this table again. One time because of the already existing Category_Child entity, and then the `@ORM\JoinTable` expression that points to the same table.

### Solution

Solution was to delete the Category_Child entity that was created from reverse engineering. If you used Category_Child entity in some $em queries, you have to select those datas othwerwise. E.g. Through the parent that holds those child datas in an ArrayCollection, or over DBAL.